# Calculation Distance Between Points

Tags: scala

I'm trying to calc the distance between two points using a Scala class. But it giving an error saying

> type mismatch;  found   : other.type (with underlying type Point) 
>   required: ?{def x: ?} Note that implicit conversions are not
>   applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method any2Ensuring in
>   object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]  and method any2ArrowAssoc
>   in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]  are possible
>   conversion functions from other.type to ?{def x: ?}

```
class Point(x: Double, y: Double) {
  override def toString = "(" + x + "," + y + ")"


  def distance(other: Point): Double = {
    sqrt((this.x - other.x)^2 + (this.y-other.y)^2 )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following compiles perfectly well for me:

```
import math.{ sqrt, pow }

class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double) {
  override def toString = s"($x,$y)"

  def distance(other: Point): Double =
    sqrt(pow(x - other.x, 2) + pow(y - other.y, 2))
}
```

---

I'd also like to point out that your `Point` would instead make more sense as a case class:

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double) { // `val` not needed
  def distance(other: Point): Double =
    sqrt(pow(x - other.x, 2) + pow(y - other.y, 2))
}

val pt1 = Point(1.1, 2.2) // no 'new' needed
println(pt1)  // prints Point(1.1,2,2); toString is auto-generated
val pt2 = Point(1.1, 2.2)
println(pt1 == pt2) // == comes free
pt1.copy(y = 9.9) // returns a new and altered copy of pt1 without modifying pt1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively use the built-in [`hypot`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/math/index.html#hypot(x:Double,y:Double):Double) function (as in *"hypotenuse"*) from the `math` module to compute the distance between two points:

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

def distance(a: Point, b: Point): Double =
  math.hypot(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y)
```