# How to fill a ListBuffer[ List[Any] ] (Scala)?

Tags: scala, list, append, indexoutofboundsexception, listbuffer

I have a ListBuffer declared like this:

```
var distances_buffer: ListBuffer[List[Any]] = ListBuffer.empty[List[Any]]
```

and I am trying to fill it with data like this:

```
for(current <- 0 to training_list_length - 1){
   //A and B are examples
   distances_buffer(current) ++= List[Any](A,B)
}
```

However I get the following error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

What am I missing?

**EDIT! More Info:**

I have a list (Named: training_list) of points and their class. (x, y, class) :

```
training_list : List[((Double, Double, String))]
```

I also have an extra point with a x and a y value given.

My goal is to calculate the euclidean distance of the extra point from each point inside the training list, and create a result which look like this:

```
//example
List((x: Double, y: Double, class: String), distance: String)

List((4.3,3.0,Iris-setosa), 1.2529964086141665), (4.4,3.0,Iris-setosa), 1.341640786499874)...
```

As you can see, in the list I want to include the coordinates of the point (from the training_list), the class of the point and also the distance.

```
for(current <- 0 to training_list_length - 1){
    val dist = eDistance(test_x, test_y, training_x(current), training_y(current))
    distances_buffer += ListBuffer[Any](training_result(current),dist)
  }
```

After the creation of this list I want to sort it based on the distances. Also stuck here!

Comment: I thik you really want this `distances_buffer += List(A, B)`. Your code was trying to add elements to the inner **List** inside the **ListBuffer** at position `current`. Whereas I believe you just want to append inner **Lists** to the buffer. - PS: Both mutability & `Any` are code smells on **Scala**, are you sure your modeling is the best for your problem?

Comment: Ok this worked! So to be clear, this is the difference between `++=` and `+=`? Also, could you explain a bit more the P.S. part?

Comment: `xs ++= ys` means add all elements of `ys` _(which has to be some kind of collection of `A`)_ to `xs` _(which has to be some kind of builder of collections of `A`)_. Whereas `xs += x` means append `x` _(which has to be an instance of `A`)_ to `xs` _(the builder)_. Also the problem was that you were trying to access an element of an empty builder by index, which was not only wrong but is not the intended use case. - I would recommend you to share with us your broader problem and how you are attempting to solve it, I am pretty sure there are more idiomatic ways to do it.

Comment: Hello, please check the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Luis, `Any` and `var` are to be avoided if possible, so here is an example that might nudge you to consider a different approach

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double, `class`: String)

def distance(a: Point, b: Point): Double =
  math.hypot(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y)

val targetPoint = Point(1,2,"Extra-point")
val training_list : List[((Double, Double, String))] = List((4.3,3.0,"Iris-setosa"), (4.4,3.0,"Iris-setosa"))
val points = training_list.map(Point.tupled)
val unsortedPoints: List[(Point, Double)] = points.map(point => (point, distance(point, targetPoint)))
unsortedPoints.sortBy(_._2)
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[(Point, Double)] = List((Point(4.3,3.0,Iris-setosa),3.4481879299133333), (Point(4.4,3.0,Iris-setosa),3.5440090293338704))
```

I have copied distance calculation from [Xavier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55309187/5205022).

Comment: B is a Double created inside the for loop each time! I would like to keep the for structure! If I am not wrong, if I include your code inside the for loop I would declare each time a new ListBuffer!

Comment: Well this really suited me perfect! I totally understand now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It seems,  for the way you name things, that you come from a **Python** background.

I would advice you to study a little bit about **Scala** first, since we are very different.
Not only on style things *(like camel case vs dash case)*, but on more fundamental things like:

- A strong and static type system. Thus, things like `Any` are usually a code smell and for 99.99% of cases, completely unnecessary.
- A mix between OOP & FP. So, you do not necessary have to become an FP expert, but there some things that are idiomatic even in the OOP side of **Scala**, like *immutability* and common operations *(higher order functions)* like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` & `reduce`.
- Our **List** is very different from the **Python** one, accessing an element by index is `O(n)` *(in **Python** it would be `O(1)`)*. A **Python** list is more like an **Array** that can be resized.
- Also, we do not really have a `for` loop. We have something called [*for comprehension*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) which is nothing more than [*syntactic sugar* for calls to `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` & in some cases `foreach`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

The list could go on, but I think my point is clear.
**Scala** is not only new syntax, is a different way to program.

---

Anyways, here is an idiomatic way to solve your problem.
*(Not necessary this is the best way, there are many variations that can be done)*

```
// First lets create some custom types / classes to represent your data.
final case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
final case class ClassifiedPoint(point: Point, clazz: String)

// Lets define the Euclidean distance function.
def euclideanDistance(p1: Point, p2: Point): Double =
  math.sqrt(
    math.pow((p1.x - p2.x), 2) +
    math.pow((p1.y - p2.y), 2)
  )
}

// This is what you need.
// Note that I made it somewhat more generic that is has to be.
// For example, instead of using the euclidean distance function directly on the body,
// we receive the distance function to use.
// Also, I use a technique called currying to split the arguments in different lists,
// This allows the caller to partially apply them.
def computeDistance(distanceFun: (Point, Point) => Double)
                   (trainingList: List[ClassifiedPoint])
                   (referencePoint: Point): List[(ClassifiedPoint, Double)] =
  trainingList.map { classifiedPoint =>
    val distance = distanceFun(classifiedPoint.point, referencePoint)
    classifiedPoint -> distance
  }
```

Which you can use like this.

```
val trainingList = List(
  ClassifiedPoint(Point(x = 4.3d, y = 3.0d), clazz = "Iris-setosa"),
  ClassifiedPoint(Point(x = 4.4d, y = 3.0d), clazz = "Iris-setosa")
)

// Partial application to create a new function.
val computeEuclideanDistance = computeDistance(euclideanDistance) _

computeEuclideanDistance(trainingList, Point(x = 3.0d, y = 0.0d))
// res: List[(ClassifiedPoint, Double)] =
//   List(
//     (ClassifiedPoint(Point(4.3, 3.0), "Iris-setosa"), 3.269556544854363),
//     (ClassifiedPoint(Point(4.4, 3.0), "Iris-setosa"), 3.3105890714493698)
//   )
```

Comment: I really apreciate your detailed answer. It is true that I need to get used to the style of Scala since I am new to this. Give me some time to evaluate and understand your way! I will let you know about the results!